# Происхождение фразеологизма «пустой звук»

Tags: этимология, фразеология, лексикология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-то информация по этому фразеологизму? Где можно посмотреть? В словарях в основном указаны варианты его значений с примерами.

***Звук пустой*** — о чем-нибудь, лишенном всякого содержания, значения.
*Пренебр.* Лишённые всякого значения, смысла слова, ничего не значащие высказывания. *Своя хата, своя семья! Эти слова не были для него пустым звуком. Он постоянно думал о своём маленьком дворе с садиком и колодцем*.

В русской литературе XVIII века такого сочетания не помню. А вот в XIX встречалось.

Comment: Если вопрос в том, считать ли выражение фразеологизмом, то здесь лучше отталкиваться от определения. [В учебнике](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-009.htm) Валгиной, Розенталя и др. представлены разные точки зрения на определение фразеологизма, но "пустой звук" (в метафорическом значении) попадает под любое из рассмотренных определений. Пользуясь навигационной панелью слева, можно посмотреть следующие параграфы учебника, в которых упоминается и "пустой звук", и даются ответы на многие вопросы о фразеологизмах, которые обычно возникают у новичка. По этимологии я ничего не нашёл.

Comment: Вот пример из XVIII в. (найдено в Нацкорпусе): "Так точно старый осел, привыкший к понуканиям и к брани своего хозяина, с терпением слушает его восклицания и ругательства… зная, что это один **пустой звук**..." (И.А. Крылов, 1792 г.). В Словаре русского языка XVIII в. выражение "пустой звук" уже присутствует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хороший вопрос...
Но дело вот в чем.

Во-первых, тут еще надо сильно подумать, фразеологизм ли это. Cлово "пустой" ведь тут используется в одном из своих прямых значений: пустые слова, пустые обещания - не может же это всё быть фразеологизмами?! То есть получается, что выражение самодостаточное и не нуждается в какой-то этимологии.

А во-вторых, даже если считать именно "пустой звук" неким устоявшимся выражением, то оно может иметь разные значения. В музыке, например, особенно в современной компьютерной, под "пустым звуком" понимают звук тишины, т.е. отсутствие звука, паузу (не всякую, но будучи человеком, совершенно далеким от музыки, не стану уточнять, какую именно), а в акустике - возвращенный "пустой", т.е. не обнаруживающий цели сигнал.
Не удивлюсь если "пустой звук" может означать и холостой выстрел. И это в дополнении к общеизвестному способу определения постукиванием того, насколько заполнен сосуд.
Такое разнообразие возможных источников ставит под сомнение возможность точной этимологии.

Comment: Ого! Спасибо за ответ! Неожиданно много вариантов.  Вот в фразеологическом словаре указаны устойчивые выражения со словом звук: " К нам идут все, кто страдает, любит и ненавидит. Для кого Родина- не пустой звук".

Comment: Все варианты весьма сомнительны.Привел их именно для того, чтобы показать, насколько дискуссионна будет любая попытка найти "истинную" этимологию. Я-то полагаю, что "пустой звук" ничем не лучше пустого стакана или пустой головы и в какой-то этимологии, помимо очевидной, не нуждается.

Comment: Да, видимо, вы правы. Тогда, мне кажется, можно воспринимать как метафору. Интересно, что немного меняется характер значения - например, в *пустой звук, пустая голова*.